# Count frequency of character from a String without using Collection?

Tags: java

Can anyone help me with this question?

**Given:**

String s="aasbkllzzzs";

**Aspected Output:**

something representing  like

```
   a has count 2
   s has count 2
   l has count 2
   z has count 3
```

---

Tried this but i think its not correct, anyone help me to modify this answer....**

```
    int[] count = new int[256];
      for(int ch; (ch = "aasbkllzzzs") >= ' ';)  //type mismatch exception,help me plz
          count[ch]++;
      for(char ch = 0; ch < count.length; ch++)
          if (count[ch] > 0)
              sysOut(ch + " appears " + count[ch] + " times");
```

Looking for someone who can give answer in 5 lines of code..
Because my interviewer was wanting answer in 5 lines of code

Comment: Your `for` loop is faulty for sure. How does `int ch` handle a `String` assignment?

Comment: Declare a Map<String, Integer> that will store the char --> occurrence mapping, and simply iterate over the chars.

Comment: @sp00m My interviewer said NOT to use Collection.. And also he wants it in 5 lines of code without using Collection

Comment: I gave you the answer yesterday man, before deleting it because some people made me realize I was doing your homework. Can't you remember at least the structure of the code I gave you ? There were 2 solutions and the shorter was one line long...

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah i am trying to say something like that we should do for this, but do not know what exactly i have to do? Yesterday my interviewr asked this question

Comment: @Dici Yes, like that answer i said to my interviewerbut he said "there will be no specif character check" u were checking with each character & counting it in static way, thats not acceptable by my interviewer..i guess you are understanding what i am talking about

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aasbkllzzzs";

        // create frequency table for 128 - ASCII Characters
        int[] freq = new int[128];

        // For each character, increment count in the frequency table
        for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
            freq[ch]++;
        }

        System.out.println("Frequencies : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
            // Print results for which count > 0
            // (char) i => Character
            // freq[i] => Frequency of character
            if (freq[i] != 0) {
                System.out.println("Char : " + (char) i + ", Count : "
                        + freq[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output :

```
Frequencies : 
Char : a, Count : 2
Char : b, Count : 1
Char : k, Count : 1
Char : l, Count : 2
Char : s, Count : 2
Char : z, Count : 3
```

Comment: This is bloody brilliant. A big plus one from me.

Comment: can you try to reduce your code in 5 lines, because my interviewer was asking in 5 lines of code

Comment: @newUser 5 lines including printing of results and class, main def?

Comment: @sujithvm i doesn't about it, just he said write code which gives output in 5 lines of code

Comment: @sujithvm Don't do it. The OP expects us to do all the work, he was acting the same yesterday with the same question.

Comment: it will be helpful if you can write comments in your answer, so that it will be helpful to some beginner to understand the code

Comment: @Dici Excuse me, your yesterday answer was like Schoolboy, which anyone can write, & its not helpful. I have given a try in mention code in my above question which is more dynamic then your static code. I was stuck here so i asked question ... You should really first read the question & according to that you have to answer it..

Comment: @newUser I have added comments.

Comment: @newUser Regarding reducing to 5 lines, main logic can be reduced to it but entire code with class def, main function, i doubt if it is possible

Comment: @sujithvm Yes great thanks. atleast next time, when i face question like above i will give them answer like yours

Comment: A minor point might be that you don't need an array that size if it's a string. `ch - 32` converts the char to a zero based index.

Answer (score 0):

In 5 lines of code:

```
public class CountCharacterWithoutCollection {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "I am an Indian";
    int[] i = new int[128];
    for (int j = 0; j < s.length(); j++) {
      i[(int) s.charAt(j)]++;
    }
    for (int k = (int) 'A'; k < (int) 'A' + 58; k++) {
      System.out.println((char) k + " " + i[k]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its more then 6 lines

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CountCharOccurrence {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Test";
        
        String temp = str.toLowerCase(); //Normalization of a string
        int[] arr = temp.chars().distinct().toArray(); //Find the distinct characters
        int chars[] = new int[256]; //An array to keep track of count of occurrences of a char
        temp.chars().map(v -> chars[v]++).toArray(); //Count the char occurrences in the array
        
        //Print the count for each distinct value
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println((char)arr[i] + " = " + chars[arr[i]]);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
t = 2
e = 1
s = 1
```